# Change header style when users sign in

Tags: theming

I am using the default template and I want the background color of the header change when a user signs in.

I know I will need to write a simple if statement like `if (user_is_logged_in()) { }` somewhere, but I don't know where to place it.

Comment: Which theme are you using on the frontend, Garland, Seven, Stark, Bartik?

Comment: You need to write it in your /theme/templates/page.tpl.php

Comment: If you're using the `Bartik` theme (default for Drupal 7) then you should edit `themes/bartik/templates/page.tpl.php`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the body tag of your theme. Some themes add classes to it indicating whether or not you are logged in.  If yours does, then you can do this via css by:

```
.logged-in #header
{
   background-color: #fff;
}

.not-logged-in #header
{
   background-color: #000;
}
```

If you don't have a body class that indicates logged in status, then you modify your page.tpl as user4035 suggested. There is no is_user_logged_in function.  Instead, it's

```
<?php
global $user;

if ( $user->uid ) {
  // Logged in user
}
else {
  // Not logged in
}
?>
```

Code Source - https://drupal.org/node/92218#comment-167984

Comment: Not quite correct; the functions user_is_anonymous() and user_is_logged_in() do exist in Drupal 7+.

Comment: Also, I would steer clear of adding logic to the template file. Separation of concerns and all that. Would be much better off checking for user status in [`hook_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) and adding to the `$variables['classes']` array.